Tesla wall charger instructions seems to conflict with wire fill maximums. How to do this install?
Ordered a Tesla wall charger and I was hoping to run the circuit this afternoon prior to receiving the unit.  The instructions indicate that the included box only fits 3/4" conduit, calls for 4ga or 6ga wire depending on breaker temperature rating, and requires a ground returned to the panel.  This would lead me to believe that I need 4-4-4-4 which won't fit in 3/4" conduit.  What is the right approach to installing this?
https://www.westerntube.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Conduit-Wire-Fill-Table.pdf

Page 22 indicates 1” conduit is acceptable.

is this a case of "rtfm"?

@JonCuster, Good  observation.  Thank you.  SolarMike, No.  The problem started out with a question about the manual and the manual seems to be providing conflicting information.

I’m not a code expert, but 1” conduit and a 3/4” gland into the box might be ok. But the instructions call out how large a hole to drill out if needed.

4-4-4-4 isn't needed here, for a bunch of reasons:

No neutral - Tesla EVSE, like most brands (if not all) available in the US, does not use neutral - that drops you to 4-4-4
Ground only needs to be 8 AWG for circuits up to 60A, which is the max. for the Tesla EVSE - that drops you to 4-4-8

But you don't even need 4 AWG. You only need 4 AWG if you are using cable. With cable, you don't use conduit (at least not in the usual way), so conduit fill isn't generally a factor.
4-4-8 wires is a 35% fill. Not great, but allowed.
And if you are actually using wires in conduit, 6 AWG will work for 60A, so now you are down to 6-6-8, which is only a 28% fill, which is much better.
In addition, conduit fill can be exceeded for short sections (I believe generally up to 24"). I'm pretty sure there would be no problem using a conduit body to transition from 3/4" at the Tesla EVSE to 1" or larger for the actual run. But that's only necessary if you oversize (4 AWG wires) and/or include extra wires (neutral) and/or run cable through conduit (which is sometimes done to provide physical protection).
As far as the 60 C and 75 C references: Most, if not all, breakers available for modern panels are rated for 75 C. However, most non-metallic cables (a.k.a., Romex) are only rated for 60 C, while most individual wires are rated for at least 75 C. Which effectively means: cable 4 AWG for 60A (48A actual) but wires 6 AWG.
Note in addition that most residential installations don't actually need that much power. 60A (48A actual) is at least double what most people need. With any size, you also need to make sure your panel and service can supply the desired power, which requires a Load Calculation. 60A added to an existing service is often a problem unless you have gas for some appliances or have some load sharing/shedding.
Fill numbers will vary by conduit type, but the pattern will be the same with all conduit types. With some metal conduit types you even get to skip the ground wire.

This will be installed off of a 100A garage panel, which was originally wired for 220 because the old owner had a small fabrication shop inside.  I just have a couple of lights and garage door openers, and occasionally I use my chop saw.  I Can't imagine a max load exceeding 40A

But is that the only panel on a 100A (or larger) service? Or is that (as is typical) a subpanel? Assuming it is a subpanel, you need to now check (a) the feed from the main panel to the subpanel (both physical size and breaker) and (b) check the Load Calculation/available capacity in the main panel. It is not unusual to (a) wire up a 100A subpanel with a 60A, 70A, 80A or 90A feed and (b) to wire it up for 90A or 100A but not have nearly that much capacity available depending on what else has been added to the main panel.

Is the Tesla appliance installed over a box in the wall or does the conduit attach to a backplate of the appliance and the wire connections are made in the appiance?

@JimStewart Based on the manual, you are attaching the actual wires (whether individual or part of a cable) directly to terminals inside the Tesla appliance. You can mount the whole thing on a junction box (and route wires in through the back) or put it directly on a wall or post and route wires in through the top or bottom.

No neutral
First, EVSEs are incapable of using neutral.  They are not chargers at all, they simply pass power through, and look at the J1772 or NACS connector! There is no pin for neutral.
The neutral myth came from very early EVs being sent home with "travel" chargers with the dominant RV park socket, that being the best public location to find big electricity "on the road".  People got this kit home and chose to install the big RV socket, even though it's overkill for home charging.  The socket needs neutral.
You'll want to oversize the wires for the amps you choose
The reason is that EV charging is a very brutal load, and we see a lot of meltdowns and fires even though everything appears to be installed correctly.
This is a great place to abandon "Fastest Charge POSSIBLE (tm)” obsessions.  As Technology Connections discusses, the hardware max for the charge station is gross overkill for home charging.
The Tesla Wall Connector can be configured to any charge rate from 12A to 48A.
Indeed, Tesla sells the exact same model/SKU of Wall Connector to malls and hotels, where you actually do want the fastest charge possible.
Extremists often go straight for 48A (extreme max charge) and 6 AWG wire, often NM Romex (extreme cheapest for that ampacity).  That is what I do not recommend.   If you gotta have 48A, use 4 AWG.
Or, don't need 48A!
I recommend upsizing wires by 2 sizes (-4 numeric sizes), but no one will listen to that,  so 1 size (-2 numeric).

I ended up going with 4-4-8 in 1" PVC conduit but I'm setting it up tonight as I had to special order the breaker.  Given this configuration, what do you think a safe load would be?

@mreff555 I would go 40A, but it would probably be fine to go 48A.  #4 wire is rated 70A at 60°C.
